# Get item details react/redux hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm building an eCommerce project using hooks for Redux and React and I'm stumped on how to get the individual details for each item. When I click on the item, I only retrieve the details of the first item in the array no matter which item is clicked with the current set up. When I use state.products.find(item => item.id === item) instead of the code below for details const, I get a TypeError: Cannot read property x of undefined. Any help is appreciated.

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <Navbar/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path='/products' component={Products}/>
          <Route exact path="/products/:prodId" component={ProductDetail}/>
          <Route exact path="/cart" component={Cart}/>
        </Switch>
      </Provider>
  );
}
```

Reducer

```
const initialState = {
    items:[],
    prodId: {},
    count: 0
 }

export default function (state = initialState, {payload,type}){
    switch(type){
        case types.GET_PRODUCTS:
            return{
                ...state,
                items: payload,
            }
        case types.GET_ITEM:
            return{
                ...state,
                prodId: payload
            }
            default:
                return state;

    }  
}
```

Actions

```
    const api = 'http://localhost:8000/products'
export const getProds = ()=> dispatch =>{
    console.log('fethcin')
    fetch(api)
    .then(res =>res.json())
    .then(data => {
        // return {type: GET_PRODUCTS, payload:data}
        dispatch({type: types.GET_PRODUCTS, payload:data});
    }
    )
}

export const getDetails = id => dispatch => {
     dispatch({type: types.GET_ITEM, payload: id})
}
```

Product

```
const Product = ({product}) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch()

const {id, title, price, isFreeShipping} = product

return (
    <div className='prod-container'>
    <div className="product">
        <h2 className='prod-title'>{title}</h2>
       <p className='prod-price'>{price}</p>
       <span className='prod-ship'>{isFreeShipping}</span>
       <button onClick={()=> dispatch(getDetails(id))}><Link to={{pathname:`/products/${id}`}}> View More </Link> </button>
       {/* <button  className='btn prod-details'>View Item</button> */}
    </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Details

```
const ProductDetail = ({match}) => {
const product = match.params.prodId

const details = useSelector(state => state.products.items.find(item => item.id === product))

const {sku, count, title, description, availableSizes, price, isFreeShipping} = details

return (
    <div className='prodDetaul'>
        <p>{title}</p>
        <p>{description}</p>
        <p>{price}</p>
        <p>{isFreeShipping}</p>
         <p>{availableSizes}</p>
         <p>{sku}</p>
         <Counter count={count}/>
         <button className='btn btn-chkot'><Link to='/cart'>Cart</Link></button>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: This is going to be a bit hard to debug without a working code sample. The link you've provided to codesandbox doesn't seem to replicate your problem as you've described it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
const details = useSelector(state => state.products.items.find(item => item.id))
```

What the statement means basically is:

> Find the first item in `state.products.items` that **has an id**.

You actually need to pass in a parameter, say, the ID of the clicked item. Could be like this:

```
const details = useSelector(state => state.products.items.find(item => item.id === myItemId))
```

Since you're using `react-router`, you can get the product ID with `props.match.params.id`.

The final solution:

```
const ProductDetail = ({ match }) => {
    const productId = match.params.id
    const details = useSelector(state => state.products.items.find(item => item.id === productId))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I figured that was why since I was able to at least one item. I've modified the code per your example, but I am still not able to retrieve the individual item and still have the type error for undefined. I think the problem may be the with the action to get the item.

Comment: looking at your code, it might be because your redux doesn't have `state.products.items`, but rather `state.items`. try that.

Comment: Hmm ill try that , the rootReducer is formatted as ' products: productReducer ' using combineReducers (code below) which is why I included products.   Would that matter? 

export default combineReducers({
    products: productReducer
})

Comment: If that's the case, `state.products.items` is correct.

Comment: I recommend you to `console.log` both the productId and `state.products.items` before `useSelector` statement.

Comment: Figured it out. I just passed the product obj into the getDetails function instead of the id and updated the useSelector fn to useSelector(state=> state.products.prodId) instead of find() and that worked.